# Split Lines If Uppercase letter Found in a line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need a regex which could split the lines if Uppercase letter found.

Example :-

```
line1 = JOHN levin have fun RAJESH is a good person SAM was ok
```

Exapecting the output as below

```
line1 = JOHN levin have fun
RAJESH is a good person
SAM was ok.
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Why is there no newline between `line1 = ` & `John` ?

Comment: try `echo $line | grep -Eo '[A-Z]+[^A-Z]+'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is what you want?

```
$ line1='JOHN levin have fun RAJESH is a good person SAM was ok'
$ sed 's/[A-Z]\+/\n&/g' <<< $line1

JOHN levin have fun
RAJESH is a good person
SAM was ok
```

Notice that a newline is added before `JOHN` since it matches your requirement. Avoid it is another question. Also your requirement is:

> I need a regex which could split the lines if Uppercase letter found.

So the expected output should be:

```
$ sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/\n\1/g' <<< $line1

J
O
H
N levin have fun
R
A
J
E
S
H is a good person
S
A
M was ok
```

Answer (score 1):

This command will split the lines before uppercase letters preceded by whitespace starting from the second occurrence (as in the example):

```
sed 's/\(\s\)\([A-Z]\)/\1\n\2/g; s/\n//'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'line1 = JOHN levin have fun RAJESH is a good person SAM was ok'|sed 's/\(\s\)\([A-Z]\)/\1\n\2/g; s/\n//'
line1 = JOHN levin have fun 
RAJESH is a good person 
SAM was ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
echo "<your string> | awk '{once_found = 0; for(i = 1; i < NF; i++){if($i ~/[A-Z]/){if(once_found){print "";} once_found++;} printf("%s ", $i);}print "";}'
```

I've put `once_found` to omit the newline between `line1 =` and `John`. I'm not sure that you really wanted that. If not, just remove `once_found` and all that is connected to it

Answer (score 0):

Another [`gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#index-RT-variable-2) based approach:

```
$ a='line1 = JOHN levin have fun RAJESH is a good person SAM was ok'

$ awk '{ORS=((NR==1)?"":"\n")RT}1' RS='[A-Z]+' <<< "$a"
line1 = JOHN levin have fun 
RAJESH is a good person 
SAM was ok
```

1. Split the input with `RS=[A-Z]+`
2. For line1, use `ORS=RT`, for other lines, use `ORS="\n"RT`.
3. print

Note that `sed` is the right tool for doing what you are trying to do. This answer is only for illustration. If you need any complex algorithm, you can use `awk` like this.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep with the `-E`xtented Regular Expressions, and `-o` which gives matches only:

```
$ line="JOHN levin have fun RAJESH is a good person SAM was ok"
$ grep -oE '[A-Z]+[^A-Z]+?' <<< "$line" 
JOHN levin have fun 
RAJESH is a good person 
SAM was ok
```